# Defining 'For' loop to iterate n characters in string?

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop

What I know:

```
list1 = ['ABCDE']
for x in list1:
     print (x)
A
B
C
D
E
```

What I need to learn:

```
list1 = ['ABCDE']
for ??? in list1:
     print (???)
AB
BC
CD
DE
```

How do I change the ??? part so it scans TWO characters at a time across per loop???

Answer (score 0):

```py
for i in range(len(list1)-1):
    print(list1[0][i:i+2])
```

Comment: Is there a way to define "i" in your example to target TWO characters as it iterates through the string? So when I print (i) it returns the two characters across the string?